# ADF: Split a JSON file with an Array of Objects into Single JSON files containing One Element in Each

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory and trying to convert a JSON file that is an array of JSON objects into separate JSON files each contain one element e.g. the input:

```
[
{"Animal":"Cat","Colour":"Red","Age":12,"Visits":[{"Reason":"Injections","Date":"2020-03-15"},{"Reason":"Check-up","Date":"2020-01-02"}]},
{"Animal":"Dog","Colour":"Blue","Age":1,"Visits":[{"Reason":"Check-up","Date":"2020-02-08"}]},
{"Animal":"Guinea Pig","Colour":"Green","Age":5,"Visits":[{"Reason":"Injections","Date":"2019-12-01"},{"Reason":"Check-up","Date":"2020-02-26"}]}
]
```

However, I've tried Data Flow to split this array up into single files containing each element of the JSON array but cannot work it out.  Ideally I would also want to name each file dynamically e.g. Cat.json, Dog.json and "Guinea Pig.json".

Is Data Flow the correct tool for this with Azure Data Factory (version 2)?

Comment: Actually, the question is not if Data Flow is the correct tool. According my experience, Data Factory can not achieve  your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I'm obviously new to adf and thought Data Flow could do this.  Could U-SQL achieve this with a gen 1 Data Lake?  I guess I'll use a Logic App or BizTalk to split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Flows should do it for you. Your JSON snippet above will generate 3 rows. Each of those rows can be sent to a single sink. Set the Sink as a JSON sink with no filename in the dataset. In the Sink transformation, use the 'File Name Option' of 'As Data in Column'. Add a Derived Column before that which sets a new column called 'filename' with this expression:

Animal + '.json'

Use the column name 'filename' as data in column in the sink.

You'll get a separate file for each row.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's great.  It's working, the problem I think I was causing myself is using schemas that included the nested arrays i.e. my actual json had an nested array named randomly and the schema couldn't handle it. Now my schema within Data Flow only contains the fixed named tags and it is working.